# BlockingCollection bounded capacity performance degradation

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, blockingcollection

I've got this C# process (.net 5.0) that reads from a zip file, deserializes the json to an object, and then transforms the json objects to DataTables for storage into a Sql Server database.  After a lot of testing and optimization, I got these three phases to be very nearly identical in processing time (via Stopwatch measurements).

I thought I could improve throughput by having separate threads for each phase, but when I tried running it, the `BlockingCollection<T>` performance went down the tubes pretty quickly.  I bounded the two queues to keep any one phase from getting too far off pace with any other, but after a short while, I got this very gap-toothed performance - spurts of activity with long periods of cpu quiescence.

Did I find some kind of degenerate case?  Does `BlockingCollection<T>` have a lot of overhead relating to the boundedCapacity?

The implementation looked like this:

```
var readingQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>(1000);
var objectQueue = new BlockingCollection<JsonObj>(1000);
var phases = new Task[3];
phases[0] = Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (;;)
    {
        var l = reader.ReadLine();
        readingQueue.Add(l);
        if (l == null)
            break;
     }
});
phases[1] = Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (;;)
    {
        var json = readingQueue.Take();
        if (json == null)
        {
            objectQueue.Add(null);
            break;
        }
        var o = Deserializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json);
        objectQueue.Add(o); 
    }
});
phases[2] = Task.Run(() =>
{
    for (;;)
    {
        var o = objectQueue.Take();
        if (o == null)
            break;
        TransformJsonObject(DataSet set, JsonObject o);
    }
}
Task.WaitAll(phases);
```

Dropping the BlockingCollections entirely and just using `Task.Run(() => reader.Readline())` for the I/O produces benefit, but parallelizing  all three phases with `BlockingCollection<T>` goes south pretty fast.

EDIT:

I tried dropping to two threads and moving the work around, but whenever there was a BlockingCollection involved it got worse than the single threaded performance and the memory consumption went through the roof.

The version that worked best was

```
var nextLine = Task.Run(() => reader.ReadLine());
for (;;)
{
    var json = nextLine.Result();
    nextLine  = Task.Run(() => reader.ReadLine());
    if (l == null)
        break;
    var o = Deserializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(json);
    TransformJsonObject(DataSet set, JsonObject o);
}
```

The timings with that version were
Total time spent Reading: 8388140 ms, Deserializing: 8870633 ms, Transform: 9240809 ms, Writing to db: 10231972 (separate queue)

but the middle 2 were synchronous.  I noticed there was a slight weight on the last step, so I tried putting read and deserialize in one thread on transform to dataset on another, and the performance was still way below the above.

That's over about 22 million lines/objects.

EDIT: to move some of the comment discussion into the main section, I was given this program to maintain.  We get daily dumps of largeish zip files.  The program starts up a configurable number of threads to process the zip files (currently set at 5).  Originally, each thread did the read/deserialize/transform to DataSet/write DataSet to Sql Server steps synchronously.

The first thing I did was to add a "write to db" thread/queue, and that worked well.

Then I started improving the times of the read/deserialize/transform steps...  Cleaning up code, swapping one deserializer for another, etc.  The timings for each of those phases were getting near identical, so I thought I'd parallelize further to try and improve the speed.

Now each of the zip file threads had one BlockingCollection for each line from the jsonl file, and one for the deserialized objects.  Each thread fires up Tasks for the reading and the deserialization.  The main file processing thread pulled from the deserialized object collection, did the transforms, and put the result on the db writing queue.

At that level of parallelization, the process ended up taking more than twice as long.  I did a minidump of the process, and I found each threads' BlockingCollections completely empty, the db writing queue empty, and almost 5 gig of ram in use somewhere.

The individual phase stats (like the time spent on file i/o and deserializing the objects) were double what just leaving the 5 file processing threads (read/deserialize/transform) steps synchronous.  That's the part that puzzled me.  Takes longer, a bunch of phantom ram, and all the queues empty when doing these things in parallel compared to doing 3 of the 4 steps synch

I did find Oflow assertions that bounded BlockingCollections would sometimes wedge when they hit their bounds but not a lot of detail as to why.

Comment: What is the expected throughput of each individual phase? How many lines read per second? How many strings deserialized to JSON objects per second? How many JSON objects transformed to datatables per second?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I added some stats and the (so far) best version performance so far

Comment: *"8388140 ms"* -- is this 8,388,140 milliseconds, or about 2 and a half hours? With 22 million items, does this mean that processing each object takes 0.4 milliseconds on average? And with a `boundedCapacity` of 1000, are the BlockingCollections completely cycling their contents every 400 milliseconds on average?

Comment: Have you tried implementing the entire dataflow in a single task and then doing something like a Parallel.ForEach?

Comment: The more detailed description of what I've got going on is 9 3-gig zip files with a configurable number of processing threads (in this case 5).  So the first 5 files get parceled out into those dataflow threads.  On each file, there's the read/deserialize/transform steps - it's those steps that I was trying to further parallelize.  Each worker thread had its own BlockingCollection and Tasks for each step

Comment: Oaou! So you have constructed basically an inverse dataflow system. Instead of having a single pipeline and parallelize each step in the pipeline, you have multiple parallel pipelines with each one composed by non-parallelized steps. My points: 1) This setup offers poor configurability, 2) it results in uncoordinated usage of the system's resources, and 3) how did you came to the conclusion that the `BlockingCollection<T>` is to blame for the overall poor performance? Lot's of other things might be the culprits (filesystem I/O bandwidth, memory bandwidth, database parallelization limits etc).

Comment: It's a program I inherited and have been trying to speed up.  When I got it originally, the only parallelization was by file unit - the read/deserialize/transform/save to db was all synch within each thread.  So I put the save to db in a separate thread and had the file processors feed that queue.  Then I swapped deserializers and cleaned up the transform code.  As the file io, deserialization, and transform costs all got closer, I thought I might speed things up by parallelizing those stages too.  But performance degraded significantly instead

Comment: Memory consumption spiked, cpu activity got very uneven and the various BlockingCollections just seemed to stop moving.  I took dumps and poked around.  It seems that my middle tweaks just found the magic balance where the sequential read/deserialize/transform was balancing out the database writes on the other queue very well.  Attempts to parallelize more seem to be vastly speeding up certain steps and making a bottleneck on the SqlBulkCopy queue.  And once the ram consumption gets high enough things go to hell

Comment: My suggestion is to throw threads and blocking collections away, and start with [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) from scratch. Create a single pipeline, and configure individually each block. It might be a good idea to put in front a [`BatchBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1), and have all the steps performed on batches instead of individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

BlockingCollection will perform poorly if all the collections are always simultaneously at their bounded capacity. Resulting in performance that mimics a single threaded implementation, but with the blocking overhead. The thread pool will also perform sub-optimally if Tasks have a lot of blocking in them. It might be worth exploring using the TryTake and TryAdd methods of the collections and allowing the idle tasks to yield.

```
for (;;;)
{
   if (!collection.TryTake(out item))
   {
       //there's nothing to do, so we'll just chill out
       await Task.Delay(/*whatever interval makes sense*/);
       continue;
   }
}
```

It's also worth noting that if you can tune the processing to work well in your current environment, that won't necessarily translate to your target environment, so you may find yourself constantly tweaking the workload between the tasks to get acceptable performance.

Since this is a pipeline of operations, you'll probably have better luck with BufferBlock and other parts of the TPL. They also have the advantage of being async/await compatible, so there's less blocking in general, and they support the same bounding limits as a BlockingCollection.

Here's a [link](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/10607/bufferblock-t-) to a tutorial that demonstrates the basics. BufferBlock allows chaining the blocks together and managing the pipeline as a unit, supports cancellation.

EDIT: If this is a long running operation, like your stats suggest, then you could benefit from using full Threads.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I was looking for what you cautioned about - if you have phases that are enough out of synch, it becomes single threaded.  I added some stats above.  What surprised me was that no matter how I shuffled things (to avoid hitting the bound), BlockingCollection implmentations went south badly.  I tried putting read + deserialize in one thread and transform in another; the BlockingCollection was empty, the ram consumption was through the roof, and I was getting long stretches of no cpu use anyway.  I'll look over your link tomorrow

Comment: "*your code effectively becomes single-threaded*" -- That's not exactly true. The threads are only blocked when their is currently nothing in their input queue to take (because the previous thread has heavier work to do), or when the output queue is currently full (because the next thread has heavier work to do). The expected behavior is that the thread with the heaviest work will be working full time, and the other two threads will be working intermittently. If the work is perfectly balanced, the performance should be nearly 3x times faster than a single-thread setup.

Comment: I took John's "your code effectively becomes single-threaded" as you describe - one thread is out of balance and becomes the gate for the others.  I was hoping for more the effect you outline - that the work was close enough to balanced that the 3 threads could work together more quickly.  But what I saw in practice was much higher ram consumption and after a while long stretches of cpu quiescence (like 15-20 seconds between any activity).  Those stretches of no cpu use got longer and longer as the program ran.